# Open Clueweb warc file with python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, warc

I would like to open the ClueWeb09 warc file in Python3, i was able to open it in python2 using this [library](https://github.com/internetarchive/warc), but I need to open it in the other python version since i need other library that are present just in python3.

I have tried to adapt [this code](https://github.com/internetarchive/warc) to python 3 but I didn't obtain a working solution. I have tried as well to use [warcio library](https://github.com/webrecorder/warcio) and [warc3-wet](https://www.pydoc.io/pypi/warc3-wet-0.2.3/autoapi/warc/index.html#) but none of this two works with ClueWeb09 format.

My final goal is to extract some features from this collections

Comment: The warcio library works for a lot of people, perhaps you could give a few more details as to what didn't work with it?

Comment: The main problem is that the ClueWeb09 collections is a warc 0.18 file, and warcio just support the 1.0 and 1.1 version. Moreover, I have read tha it doesn't use the standard \r\n end-of-line markers and some of its records are ill-formed.

Comment: That's good to know, I am extending warcio to handle records with bad formats! However, it's not sufficiently openly available for me to actually look at it.